# Why does the Intellij test runner count tests incorrectly?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, counter

At some point during a testing run in Intellij test runner, the "total" test count begins to increase (as though its finding more tests while running), but the summary displayed when the tests are finished shows something like this:

`Stopped. Tests failed: 5, passed: 3090, ignored: 392 of 3825 tests - 4 m 22 s 836 ms`.

I'm not the best at math, but pretty sure `5 + 3090 + 392 != 3825`.

I see nothing in Intellij bug reports mentioning something like this, so I'm wondering if there might just be a setup issue on my part, or something else entirely...

Comment: Is the issue reproduced for you with 2019.3 (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)? Do you experience the same issue with little projects?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho The IDE is 2019.2.3; haven't updated to 2019.3  I did create a small sample project, and could not reproduce the behavior.  So there must be some kind of trigger in the code/test base. I just can't find it, or narrow it down to a single test.  It is bothersome, but maybe not so much to spend many many hours tracking down... But I was hopeful somebody had seen similar, and already figured out what triggers it.

Comment: According to your output the tests were "Stopped", so they were stopped with Stop button or somehow else. In this case - "Tests failed: 5, passed: 3090, ignored: 392 of 3825 tests" can be explained as: 3825 tests were scheduled,  only 5 + 3090 + 392 have managed to finish before being stopped. Please clarify how the testing was stopped? What test framework was used? Thanks

Comment: Hi Olga.... No, that's not it.   Tests have been added since the other day, but right now, as the tests start running, the IJ panel starts off with what appears to be a correct total: "passed X of 3512 tests".   But when there's just a few hundred tests remaining, that total starts to climb rapidly as each test runs, ending up showing some 3850 tests.   Me (and another team member here) have tried to narrow it down to find the test that starts the total climbing, but no luck so far...  Thanks!

Comment: Please define the test framework that you use and create an issue at YouTrack if possible (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues).